# Prove that the only negative real zeroes are at the integers

Tags: elliptic-curves, zeta-functions

Let $$L(C,s)=\prod_{p\mid\Delta}(1-a_{p}p^{-s})^{-1}\cdot\prod_{p\nmid\Delta}(1-a_{p}p^{-s}+p^{1-2s})^{-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$
be the Dirichlet series of the Hasse-Weil $L$-function of an elliptic curve $C$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. 
My question is: Prove that the only negative real zeroes are at the negative integers.

**Hint**: This is a direct consequences of the fact that the poles of the gamma-factors in the completed $L$-function imply the existence of the zeros of $L$.

Comment: The BSD conjecture suggests that L-functions may have zeros at $s=1$.

Comment: @yzhao: Yes;, I know, but I am asking for negative values.

Comment: Hasse proved $\vert a(p)\vert<2\sqrt{p}$, which suggests the infinite product absolutely converges when $\Re s>3/2$.

Comment: @yzhao: Yes, but these zeros are the poles of the gamma-factors.

Comment: Wiles proved that $L(C,s)$ is entire and $\Lambda(C,s)=\Lambda(C,2-s),\Lambda(s)=L(C,s)\Gamma(s)N^s$(N is a real number). The functional equation implies $\Lambda(C,s)$ is analytic and zero-free in the left half-plane, which forces $L(C,s)$ to vanish at negative integers(in order to cancel the poles of gamma-factors).

Comment: @yzhao: Ok and thank you very much.